# Google Place API Not showing Right Listing

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google Place API. We are using a Google map on each location page we have. The issue I am having with this one location page is that it is grabbing an individuals google map listing that works for us instead of the overall business listing.

Here is the test page: http://www.bkd.com/about-us/locations/nebraska/lincoln-test.htm

Here is the listing that shows currently: https://www.google.com/maps?ll=40.814142,-96.702888&z=15&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=embed&cid=13581319227403147888

This is the listing I am needing it to show: https://www.google.com/maps/place/BKD+LLP/@40.8140716,-96.7028712,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x8796befcf76bff05:0xa6eb8785f0c0d8e4?hl=en-US

Here is my code on my page:

```
<iframe
 width="360"
 height="270"
 frameborder="0" style="border:0"
 src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAjae4NHf45sLSplhcsEDpFxj7P9sp8-PI
&q=BKD+LLP,lincoln+NE &zoom=15
">
</iframe>
```

How do I get the listing to show the one I want instead of the individuals listing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear in the sense that what is the required behavior. However, after looking at you request it can be analysed that the REST API call is not the same as in the documentation. After you know the coordinates of the location you want to display that place on your map.

Try this API request that uses the Places Library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

See here for [Places Library overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries).

And use this sample code:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for writing back. I have done what you suggested and I am not getting any map now. I read through the documentation and am just having a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong.

http://www.bkd.com/about-us/locations/nebraska/lincoln-test.htm